# Differences between the way WAMP and XAMPP handle vhosts?

Tags: apache, xampp, wamp, vhosts

I'm switching from WAMP to XAMPP and XAMPP has broken my vhosts. It won't allow access to them.

> "You don't have permission to access
>   the requested directory. There is
>   either no index document or the
>   directory is read-protected."

The Apache error log says:

> "[error] [client 127.0.0.1] client
>   denied by server configuration"

What does WAMP set that XAMPP doesn't in order to make the vhosts work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possible reasons:

- You are missing a `<Directory>` container to allow access to that file tree:

  ```
  <Directory "C:/Foo/Bar/">
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ```
- You are using PHP but `index.php` is not defined as directory index:

  ```
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  ```
- The directory is read-protected

Comment: I was missing the directory container. Thanks for your answer.